# Неперехватываемые исключения Multithreading

Tags: java

Считается, что в Multithreading методе run() блока catch() для обработки исключений не существует. Для этого надо пользоваться Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler interface.

```
public class Tester extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            File file = new File(""); 
            file.getCanonicalFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {           //контроллируемое
            Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NullPointerException e){    //неконтроллируемое

        }
    }

}
```

Растолкуйте, ибо я, скорее всего, неправильно понимаю данную формулировку.

Comment: [Исключения в Java, Часть II (checked/unchecked) tutorial][1]

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/225585/

Comment: я знаю, что такое checked/unchecked

Comment: Что конкретно непонятно? Я не вижу чёткого вопроса. В данном случае наследники RuntimeException (кроме NullPointerException) будут пойманы зарегестрированным объектом UncaughtExceptionHandler, если таковой был привязан предварительно.

Comment: как не существует catch(), если я его ясно использую на примере?

Comment: или это значит, что метод run() не обозначается как throws ?

Comment: Вы бы для начала определились, что именно вы понимаете под "контроллируемое"/"неконтроллируемое".

Comment: Неконтроллируемые - Error и RuntimeException потомки. Все эти исключения не перехватываются обработчиком исключений, так как Error возникают в самой системе и они не предотвращаются, а RuntimeException возникают по вине программиста, и их можно избежать. Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, действительно не все исключения попадают в `try/catch`.  
Класс Thread имеет статический метод `setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`,
который, как понятно из названия, задает обработчик, который на вход принимает объект класса  `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

```
   public class CustomUncaughtHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
            System.out.println("Unhandled exception"+throwable + "has been received from thread"+ thread);
        }
    }
```

Соответственно, установить можно следующим образом:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomUncaughtHandler());
```

Естественно, это можно было бы сделать намного быстрее, так как это функциональный интерфейс, то есть с помощью лямбда выражений, опять же, если Вы хотите использовать этот обработчик в одном месте.

Если я вообще правильно понял Ваш вопрос. Если что-то непонятно, то задавайте вопрос, желательно поконкретнее.

Answer (score 0):

[[@romashechka](/users/17582/romashechka)](/users/17582/romashechka), мне кажется, Вы не о том думаете.

Подумайте, а куда вообще можно передать управление (ведь exception это передача управления, скажем так -- весьма специфический return) **из потока** (thread)?

Даже чисто технически у потока родителя и потока вбрасывающего исключение **разные стеки** (да, я знаю, что в языке Java концепция thread-родитель вообще отсутствует).

Вот попробуйте запрограммировать (умозрительно) на виртуальной машине такую ситуацию и Вам придется принять те же "правила игры", что и авторам языка.